How sorting happens behind the scene in spark
consider, I have a single 100 GB csv file, I need to create a ranking column let say 'rank' based on 'customer_spends_in_dollar' col.
df = spark.read.csv('file.csv')    
(
    df
    .withColumn(
        'rank',
        F.rank().over(
            Window().orderBy('customer_spends_in_dollar')
        )
    )
).display()

spec: 8 GB Driver, 8 GB 2 worker node, 2 Core on each
idea being, for this absurd no. is to emphasize, there is not a possibility of entire data being loaded on a single node(driver).
The very first operation for above transaformation would be sorting the entire dataframe, now as per my understanding, sorting individual partition files(part files) on worker node, would not sort the data entirely, it will only sort a portition of data, and further it needs to be sorted entirely at once and then I see a problem, how can this data be assembled at driver node, because it cannot fit in the memory. this is where my understanding STOPS.
ofcourse, but spark is able to do above things, i have checked, it is just a longs duration job. but HOW ?

Rank based on custid? What an odd idea.

I agree, but the problem is not question, it the ideology how it is being solved, let me change the cols. But I got your concern

I will answer later

Answer is correct. Can u accept pls?

If there is no partition vaue, you will see the sort / order by moving the data to a single partition. I.e. the complete data frame is sorted there.With all ensuing OOM issues etc.
The basic tenet of Spark is parallelism, but it needs distribution of data by grouping or partitioning based on some column value(s) to allow filling of multiple partitions. If that is not then case, then single partition sorting is what happens instead of doing local (partition) sorts firstly.
